# setOnClickListener() does not work in my custom View

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

I have a custom View, a Button, but `setOnClickListener()` does not work.

```
class ButtonReadBarcode extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton {

    public String ma_vach = "";
    private Activity ac = null;

    public ButtonReadBarcode(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ac = Global.getActivity( context);
        init();
    }
    private void init(){
        setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setText("Scan barcode ...");
        setAllCaps(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener( View.OnClickListener l) {
        super.setOnClickListener(l);
        // this line does now work        
        setText("I want this text show when click");
    }

}
```

not any error messages

Comment: documentation : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android button onclick override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575959/android-button-onclick-override)

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding your setOnClickListener, it will only work if you call it somewhere else, then it will do what you pass as parameter+set the text as you wrote.

To override the basic click of the button you should override onClick:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     setText("I want this text show when click");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this problem you can try the following code it is working for me:

```
public class CustomButton extends AppCompatButton {
    public CustomButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener l) {
        super.setOnClickListener(l);
        setText("asdf");
    }
}
```

Here is the XML:

```
<com.example.stackoverflowquestions.CustomButton
            android:id="@+id/customButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Custom Button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

And simply use it in MainActivity as:

```
 CustomButton customButton =  findViewById(R.id.customButton);
        customButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: That will work, but setting an empty onClickListener is a unnecessary workaround, it's better and simpler to just override onClick.