# Creating CustomButton Extends Button to pre set conditions which called before onclick

Tags: java, onclicklistener, android-button

I have extended the Button class and I want to run methods like `isInternetConnected` and `isUserLoggedIn` when user click to this button and after perform `onclick` if all condition satisfied.

**For Example if I created simple form where user name, email, phone no. and Submit Button placed. When user click on submit first it checks `isInternetConnected` and `isUserLoggedIn` if this satisfies then perform final operation saves user data to server or anywhere.**

```
public class CustomButton extends Button {
private static final String TAG = "CustomButton";

public CustomButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}
```

**If this is possible then I don't need to check every time**

```
  `mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!isInternetConnected) {
                //show dialog or snackbar
            } else if (!isUserLoggedIn) {
                //show dialog or snackbar
            }else {
                // save data
            }
        }
    });`
```

Comment: Can you make clear what is the issue?

Comment: I think this answers your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575959/android-button-onclick-override

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: @Thirumalai I want to create custom button so that where I use that button, when a user clicks, first it checks predefined methods then go to on click event.

Comment: @SamirSpahic I checked the link u provided but its not what I am looking for.  I want to create custom button so that where I use that button, when a user clicks, first it checks predefined methods then go to on click event.

please tell me if any how its possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now i understand what you are asking. Ideal solution for your problem would be AOP (aspect oriented programming). 
These should help you:

https://medium.com/@jdvp/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android-159054d52757
https://fernandocejas.com/2014/08/03/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android/

This lib should help you:

https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/